# SQL запрос считающий количество пользователей по определённым условиям

Tags: sql

Как составить запрос к таблице users который считает количество пользователей, рождённых (поле birthday) в каждом году (из тех, что есть в birthday) по следующим правилам:
во первых: анализируются только те пользователи, у которых указан год рождения
во вторых: выборка отсортирована по году рождения в прямом порядке?

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  birthday DATE,
  email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  created_at timestamp
);
INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, email, birthday) VALUES
  (1, 'Sansa', 'sansa@winter.com', '1999-10-23'),
  (2, 'Jon', 'jon@winter.com', null),
  (3, 'Daenerys', 'daenerys@drakaris.com', '1999-10-23'),
  (4, 'Arya', 'arya@winter.com', '2003-03-29'),
  (5, 'Robb', 'robb@winter.com', '1999-11-23'),
  (6, 'Brienne', 'brienne@tarth.com', '2001-04-04'),
  (7, 'Tirion', 'tirion@got.com', '1975-1-11');
```

Comment: прямой порядок имеется ввиду хронологически ?

Comment: @noname2019 да, всё верно.

Comment: не уверен что это можно сделать за один запрос (потому удалил свой ответ внимательно прочитав ещё раз что вам нужно) я в итоге поправил код но он выводил всего лишь список пользователей которые год не null и в хронологическом порядке сортируя по году. Может и можно избегая процедур это сделать но я не знаю как или же просто вынести эту обработку вне mysql (выбрать всех кто не null и потом посчитать одинаковые года)

Comment: @noname2019 мой вариант:
   USE Наша_БД
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
   WHERE  birthday LIKE '1975%')
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
   WHERE  birthday LIKE '1999%')
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
   WHERE birthday LIKE '2001%')
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
   WHERE birthday LIKE '2003%')
но мне он кажется слишком большим и неправильным

Comment: не уверен что есть короче решения (разве что использовать циклы с курсорами внутри процедуры перебирая года) но я сомневаюсь что тот код будет короче. Мне тоже кажется что есть решения и получше. Но извините тут я не знаю как(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(nusers.id), nusers.birthday
FROM (SELECT id, first_name, email, SUBSTRING(birthday, 0, 4) birthday FROM users ORDER BY birthday) nusers
WHERE nusers.birthday IN (1999, 2000, 2001) GROUP BY nusers.birthday
```

Comment: Предложение ORDER BY не допускается в представлениях, встроенных функциях, производных таблицах, вложенных запросах и обобщенных табличных выражениях, если вместе с ним не указано предложение TOP, OFFSET или FOR XML.  Выдаёт ошибку и не работает

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(YEAR(birthday)) 
from users
WHERE birthday IS NOT NULL
group by year(birthday)
```

Спустя несколько часов нашёл правильный ответ самостоятельно.